# No database selection openerp connection

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I imported a database through psql interface, the database exists but on the OpenERP connection interface, the database imported is not listed.

What should I do to get the database imported listed in the connection interface of OpenERP ??

Cheers

Comment: just the the user of the database is same as the user of database assigned when installing openerp
let me if know any more info

Comment: Please provide the environment 
os and other stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the database is owned by the database user configured in the OpenERP configuration file - openerp usually.

Another situation when you can see an empty list for database selection is when your openerp-server didn't start for some reason. You have access to the login interface because openerp-web has started but as there is not server behind openerp-web cannot get the list of databases.

Comment: That was the issue. Cheers